# duplicate content in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new in xsl. I was trying to add the `<quote>` tag in between the `<para>`.tag. but the output printing twice.

Here is my xsl code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pretrans">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[count(child::node())=0]" mode="pretrans"/>
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <poc>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </poc>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text">
        <chapter>
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(child::node()[@style='H5']/preceding-sibling::p)+1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[position()&lt;$pos]" mode="presec"/>
            <section>
                <xsl:variable name="nodesets" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[position()>=$pos]" mode="pretrans"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodesets" mode="postsec"/> <!---->
            </section>
        </chapter>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p" mode="presec">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@style='H2'">
                <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@style='H4'">
                <subdivision>
                    <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>
                </subdivision>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p" mode="postsec">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::p[@style='H5'][1]/preceding-sibling::p)+1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::p)+1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="styleblock" select="count(preceding-sibling::p[@style='BlockStyle'][1]/preceding-sibling::p)+1"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@style='H5'">
                <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(child::node())=0"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <paragraph>
                    <xsl:if test="@style='BlockStyle'">
                        <quotes>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </quotes>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </paragraph>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

expected output:

```
<poc>
<chapter>
<section>
<paragraph>
<quote>
Hi welcome to new year 2022
</quote>
Hi welcome to new year 2022
</paragraph>
</section>
</chapter>
</poc>
```

The message is printing twice.
can anyone help me in this.

Comment: I haven't been doing with XSLT for long time, but isn't `<xsl:if test="@style='BlockStyle'"><quotes><xsl:apply-templates/></quotes></xsl:if><xsl:apply-templates/>` the cause?

Comment: yes. ```<xsl:if test="@style='BlockStyle'"><quotes><xsl:apply-templates/></quotes></xsl:if><xsl:apply-templates/>```. it is cause the issue

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs delete the first or the second

```
<paragraph>
   <xsl:if test="@style='BlockStyle'">
      <quotes>
         <xsl:apply-templates/><!-- First -->
      </quotes>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates/><!-- Second -->
</paragraph>
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?